# PyQt and C++ Qt Signal slot communication ? Is it possible ? Any other ways

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I wanted to know if it is possible to attach a signal in PyQt to a slot in C++ Qt that communicates via TCP/IP . Or are there mechanisms for passing data back and forth between two different applications processes one PyQt the other C++ Qt ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just use normal QUdpSocket on localhost (127.0.0.1) and pick two ports (say 20230 and 20231) for forward/backward coms.... I do this quite often to do IPC between programs, its nice and easy.

Comment: Have a look at this previous answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388606/any-idea-for-running-qt-signals-slots-over-network